# XCode SpriteKit template is not rendering fullscreen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skview

In XCode, I created a new Game Project using SpriteKit and when running in Simulator, all I see is an SKView with a Hello Label. And that SKView I'm afraid occupies only 2/3rd of the screen.

[I added a red border to the SKView and it now looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htx88.png)
How can I make this full screen? I'm a newbie in game programming and this is my first attempt. So your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I managed to fix it. Anybody else experiencing similar issue should try adding a LaunchScreen.storyboard file to the project. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: I have also experienced this in the last day with a fresh Game template app. Could you provide more detail about what you did with the LaunchScreen.storyboard? I do not seem to be repeating your success.

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out; rather than adding a storyboard file manually, it needs File > New > "Launch Screen", then in the project General settings this needs to be set under the launch screen setting

Comment: I don't understand how this is really the answer but I agree @AlexAnderson describes this perfectly. What the what??